# Why does this not print anything

Tags: c++

So I have this, and if I comment out the bottom part, from `int count = 0;` to `return 0;` it will print, but in this case, nothing prints out. Even adding `cout << "Test"` in the beginning does nothing. It all compiles fine though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text = "Smith, where Jones had had \"had had\", had had \"had\". \"Had had\" had had the examiners' approval.";

    string search = "had";

    int length = (int) text.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        text [i] = tolower(text [i]);
    }

    cout << text;

    int count = 0;
    for (int index = 0; (index = text.find(search)) != string::npos; index += search.length()) {
        count++;
        }

    cout << "There are " << count << " occurences of \"" << search << "\".\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your last for loop is an infinite loop because `search` is always found in `text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile it with `g++ -g a.cpp` then run it with gdb, you'll find that it's in an infinite loop.

What is pointed out in @xymostech 's answer is correct though. Although if the loop does end, the buffer will be flushed before the code ends.

Your pattern is always found in the string and therefore the `text.find(search)` never returns `string::npos`

Answer (score 2):

Your first loop is fine, but your second loop gets stuck at index 19, because you're always searching from the beginning of text.